# Automate clicking Javascript button error - no luck with mechanize or selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, mechanize

I am trying to write a script that automates logging into a website. I get no problem by filling in the username and password fields but I can't get to click the 'Logon' button. Have tried numerous ways but it just won't 'click' this button.

When I inspect the website this is what I find as way of identifying the button:

```
<input type="button" class="clsButton" id="Logon" name="Logon" tabIndex="3" value="Logon" title="Logon"> </input>
```

Later on, as an alternative in a Javascript excerpt, there is a method called Logon_click() which I assume is the method that gets triggered when the button is clicked.

I have tried the following:

With selenium:

```
def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(25)
        self.base_url = "https://trakcarelabwebview.nhls.ac.za/trakcarelab/csp/logon.csp"
        self.verificationErrors = []

    def test_labtrak_driver(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
        driver.find_element_by_id("USERNAME").send_keys("XXX")
        driver.find_element_by_id("PASSWORD").send_keys("XXXX")
## tried using both, does not click Logon button
        driver.find_element_by_id("Logon").click()
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("clsButton").click()
```

And I have tried with mechanize as well:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('https://trakcarelabwebview.nhls.ac.za/trakcarelab/csp/logon.csp')
br.select_form(nr = 0)
br.form['USERNAME'] = "XXX"
br.form['PASSWORD'] = "XXXX"
br.select_form(name="fSSUser_Logon")\
## once again numerous ways, not working
br.form.action="Logon_click()"
br.submit()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error with the selenium code?

Comment: Can you please try this way and post any errors it may throw. `foo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='Logon']")` [newline] `foo.click()`

Comment: @NoelSegura Absolutely no errors. It just does not log in.

Comment: that is strange indeed, can you please try your code with a different web page? That might help to give some hindsight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found your problem

remove the slash from the url.

```
driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
```

to

```
driver.get(self.base_url)
```

This should solve

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you - that fixed it. Suppose that's the mistakes I'll get if I am modifying existing code!

Comment: @Albert actually I think the problem is with the webpage, if you try to go to the address with the slash at the end, you get a broken version that shouldn't be there

Comment: I got the idea that it is a bit a patched up job of a website, just by looking at the comments in the code.